# Is there a way to increase the font size in KDE Neon Developer Edition?

Tags: kde, fonts

**I tried a lot to change the font size and also tried to find a solution for the same through search engines. But none of them could solve my problem.**

Is there a way to increase the font size in [KDE Neon Developer Edition](https://neon.kde.org/develop) ?

*Here is an image of the system settings window of my KDE Neon Developer Edition*

I have not found any settings related to font. (Even on search)

[image: Image of systems settins of my KDE NEON DEVELOPER]

Answer (score 1):

Go to
`System Settings --> Appearance --> Fonts` (This works in KDE Plasma 5.19.4 in KDE Neon 18.04 user edition. It might depend on the plasma version. Search for Fonts in system settings)

[image: fonts settings]
Now increase size of all the fonts in use to suit your needs.

Comment: I have already search for that setting and found none. I am using the latest KDE Version and yet this problem occurs.
I found no such setting as font.

Comment: This works for me, however how can I set this programmatically?

Comment: @arshbot As in, you want to set this with a command? I don't know, ask a new question.